# How to update fragment data using RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have a `ViewPager` with 12 `fragments`. I need to get data from API and update the fragments when scrolling. How do I update the contents of fragment, with only one fragment updating for 12 pages?

My fragment layout fragment_item:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/surface">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/khaire"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Overal Working Hour"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="January"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

My main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int num_pages = 12;
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
    mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
  private class ScreenAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
 public ScreenAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return new SliderFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return num_pages;
    }
}
```

My SlideFragment class:

```
public class SliderFragment extends Fragment {

Toolbar toolbar;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item,container,false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Now I want to have same fragment while scrolling the page but with diff texts how could I do that... And if possible use `RecyclerView` also.

Comment: Describe more about question with some code.

Comment: Use Singleton class for this..

Comment: This one is best solution which worked for me. You can override this method in `Fragment` so that when it is visible to user then only it will update  `@Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
        if (menuVisible) {
           //code to update fragment                                                                                          
    }
    }`

Comment: could you please so a simple code for example

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new Class (UpdatingFragment) with public abstract `updateView();` that extends Fragment.

Create your `SliderFragment` by extending `UpdatingFragment` instead of Fragment

In the `SliderFragment` in `onCreateView()` at the end call `updateView()`.

Write an overwrite method in your `SliderFragment` for what you need to update (anything you want to show on the UI)

Adjust your `screenAdapter` to return and take `UpdatingFragment`’s instead of Fragments.

Now whenever your fragments `onCreateView` gets called all their UI data gets updated, and if you create a list of `SliderFragments` and pass that into your adapter instead of creating new ones, you can just run a for loop over that list and call `updateView()` for each fragment.